# IE11 only printing first page of scrolling pop-up

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm trying to print a long list of elements on the screen.  In IE, only the first page prints, and the remaining elements are cut off.  In other browsers, it prints as expected.  This is not in an iframe, but it is in a pop-up (positioned absolutely on the page).  Also worth noting is that the long list of elements is in a scrolling `<div>` in the pop-up (since the list is too long to fit on the screen).

Here are some things I know do not work to fix this problem:

1. removing absolute positioning from everything on the page
2. removing floats from the page
3. setting all overflow properties to visible (or commenting them out)
4. removing all height properties from all elements

Unfortunately, since I'm not sure what's causing the issue, I can't create a code sample that replicates the problem to provide here as a debug tool.  This is part of a much larger Angular 2 application.

Comment: set the height of the popup div to 100% with overflow hidden in a print only media query. @media print{
            #divpopup{height:100%;overflow:auto;}
        }

Comment: @RobParsons I tried it, unfortunately it doesn't work.  The print just has scroll bars now surrounding the whole page.  I also tried adding those height and overflow properties to all the other elements that are parents of the list I need to print, but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it was absolute positioning after all, but in combination with calculated page heights.

The root component of the app had a calculated CSS height, like calc(100vh - 200px).  Replacing that height with height: auto in a @print media for the component allowed removing position: absolute from the pop-up to actually work.

As a side note, I bet this problem would have surfaced if the root component had *any* fixed height, not necessarily just a calculated height.

Summary: If you run into this problem, keep an eye out for fixed height parent elements being used in combination with absolute positioning.